# element LinearLayout must be declared

Tags: android-studio, android-linearlayout

I have updated my android studio and now I have a problem in my main.xml, it displays the following error:
`element LinearLayout must be declared`

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/monBouton"
        android:text="Cliquez ici !"
        >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the error message:

> error : Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> error : cannot find symbol variable action_settings

How can I solve it?

Comment: include the complete error message.

Comment: the complete error message was included, thanks

Comment: I have the same error, the reason is because of I put xml file inside `drawable/` instead of `layout/` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have `action_settings` defined inside menu's xml file

```
res/menu/yourmenufile.xml
```

like this :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.app" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 32):

Your layout files must be in `res/layout` folder.

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: this solved my problem. Usually this is the answer for general cases.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same Error. Problem was, i had my dialogfragment layout in the menu folder instead of the layout folder